# Accessing variable from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have following script

```
<script>

var Obj = {
        purpose_1: {
            defaults: { 
                purpose:{ my_variable:"Test" } 
            },
            activity: function() {
                console.log( Obj.purpose_1.defaults.purpose.my_variable );
            }
        },

        purpose_2: {

        }
   }

   Obj.purpose_1.activity();

</script>
```

I am accessing `my_variable` and getting output `Test` in console from line

```
console.log( Obj.purpose_1.defaults.purpose.my_variable );
```

Is there any short cut way like

`this.my_variable`

to access `my_variable` instead of this long path

`Obj.purpose_1.defaults.purpose.my_variable`

Thanks.

Comment: `this.defaults.purpose.my_variable` is one of them

Comment: `this.defaults.purpose.my_variable` would work as long as you continue to call the function the way you currently do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activity: function () {
    return function() {
        //this now refers to Obj.purpose_1.defaults.purpose
        console.log(this.my_variable);
    }.call(Obj.purpose_1.defaults.purpose);
    // call overrides the context in which the function is executed
}
```

Return a function bound to the context you need! Here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATjrh/).

See the [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method at MDN.

Comment: Made own sandbox... Well, nice (: +1 But do not forget to save reference to current context: `var self = this` before `return function(){ ... }.call()` will give direct access to both objects.

Comment: Did you intend this answer as a joke? (I'm not sure whether to provide serious feedback or not.)

Comment: Oh great, thanks. there can be also use .call(this.defaults.purpose);

Answer (score 2):

Because of javascript objects are implicitly passing by reference, you may create shortcuts for yourself like this:

```
activity: function() {
    var p = this.defaults.purpose; // shortcut

    console.log(p.my_variable); // property
}
```